# Construct a locally concave polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I'd like to construct a polynomial $f(x)$ such that:

- $f(x)$ has roots $0$ and $b$ where $b>0$ (and possibly others)
- $f′(a)=0$ for given $a$, where $0<a<b$
- $f(a)=1$ (ie. there's a local maxima at $(a,1)$ )
- $f(x)$ is concave on the range $[0,b]$

$f(x)$ can be of any degree, and it isn't important what happens outside  $[0,b]$.

I'm able to construct a polynomial with the desired roots and local maxima, it's the concavity condition I'm struggling with.

I'm aware that there's an infinite number of solutions, so I'm much more interested in the procedure of ensuring concavity than any one example solution.

Comment: Edited because I meant concave, not convex.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure concavity on $[0,b]$ you want your polynomial to meet the condition $f''(x) < 0$ for each $x \in [0,b]$

Comment: Absolutely! But I'm not sure how to enforce that requirement when solving for the coefficients of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

So let us say $f$ is a vector of coefficients. $X = [1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^N]$, and $D$ is the differential operator for polynomials. For convexity/concavity you could then encourage the second derivative to have a sign by adding a cost term $$c_\epsilon\|XD^2f \pm \epsilon\|$$ this will make the derivative having one sign cost slightly more than having the other sign. Then the $c_\epsilon$ would be a diagonal matrix working as a mask to specify the set of points, i.e. "interval".